# How to access items from ListView connected to SQL Server

Tags: java, android, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a listview with textviews that bring information from a table in sql server as id, description and quantity. I need that when the user clicks on an item in the listview, open another activity with that information that the user selected, the user can edit and save in the database.

I have the following code that queries the database and fills the listview, but I can't find the way to pass the information to another activity. Any help?

public void getProd() {
         comandSQL = "Select * from Inventory where [Code] = '"+loccode+"' order by [Bin Code]";

```
    try {
        Statement statement = MainActivity.connect.createStatement();
        rs = statement.executeQuery(comandSQL);
            List<Map<String, String>> data = null;
        data = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();

        while(rs.next()){         
             Map<String, String> datanum = new HashMap<String, String>();
             datanum.put("idProd", rs.getString("No_"));
             datanum.put("desc", rs.getString("Description"));
             datanum.put("ubic", rs.getString("Bin Code"));
             datanum.put("cant", rs.getString("Inventory"));
             data.add(datanum);
        }
        String[] from = {"idProd","desc","ubic","cant"};
        int[] views = {R.id.id_prod,R.id.descripcion, R.id.ubicacion,R.id.cant}; 
        AD = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.list, from, views);
        Lista.setAdapter(AD);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("ERROR",e.getMessage());
    }       
}
```

Comment: set list item click listener and pass information with intent & retrieve the info using Bundle from another activity. Do a little research, you will get it.

Answer (score 0):

You want to set up a click listener for each listview item:

```
@Override 
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // Do something when a list item is clicked
}
```

When the item is clicked, you need to gather the data from that view and then simply start a new activity passing that data via an Intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, YourNewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("MyData", userData.toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Yes, I had done that, but the problem is that the same textviews to use all the information, use the same model with textview xml repeat to display 300 records database, then I don't know how to get the information for textview of a list item, not if I explained.

Comment: from your adapter, you should be able to do a getView() given the position or id of the view clicked (itemClicked = adpater.getView(pos) ). That's in the click listener above.  You can get get the children of a view with something like Texview text = itemclicked.getChildAt(index)

Comment: I have another problem, due to I use textviews, listview is not selectable, I have added to xml model a button to repeat on each element of the listview, but I still have the same problem, I can't obtain the information that is in each textview of each item of listview –